# How to use Rar.exe to Rar folders in their original name

Tags: windows, command-line, backup, powershell, zip

I googled for days and could not find much help.

I am trying to make a powershell .PS1 file to run it every 30 minutes to check if there is a new folder, It will RAR contents inside the folder and keep the original folder the same. Rar the files within those folders and delete the source.

For example:

I will set the Destination to:

Data = "C:\test"

NewDestination = "C:\backup"

And I will have folders:

"C:\test\folder 1"

- somedata.txt
- files.exe
- my video.mp4

"C:\test\folder 2"

- somedata.txt
- somedata2.txt
- somedata3.doc

It does not matter if those folder has content inside or not, I want to make rar file for those folders in their original name and delete the original folder.

I will have this:

"C:\test\folder 1\folder 1.rar"

"C:\test\folder 2\folder 2.rar"

When files in subfolders are rared and deleted, move the main folder to another destination.

NewDestination = "C:\backup"

"C:\backup\folder 1\folder 1.rar"

"C:\backup\folder 2\folder 2.rar"

foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem -dir C:\test)

I tried with some of these lines but could not make it happen.

If you have something which might help me, plz do share.

**Thank you and sorry if it's a repeated question.**

Answer (score 1):

Cole
Try something like this

```
$Source = "C:\temp"
$Destination = "D:\Backup"
# Gather Subfolders only (-directory parameter). If there are files on the root source remove this parameter to collect all files and folders
$Tree = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Directory | Select-Object -Property Name, FullName 

# Treatment
foreach ($dir in $tree)
    {
    # to avoid to overwrite an existing archive file, use the parameter -update
    # the name of the destination archive file will be the same of the source dir
    Compress-Archive -Path $dir.fullName -DestinationPath $Destination\$($dir.name) -CompressionLevel Optimal -Update
    Write-Verbose "$($dir.FullName) has been archived to $Destination\$($dir.name)"
    # At this step, a new .zip archive has been created, but the source folder is already present, then go to delete it
    Remove-Item -Path $dir.FullName -Force
    Write-Verbose "$($dir.FullName) has been removed"
    }
```

I use the native cmdlet Compress-archive (Powershell>2) with optimal compression

Olivier

Comment: Thank you very very much. I modified a little bit and all working perfectly.

Thanks once again ^__^